# Select statement only searches by check boxes when kept in the where statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have 21 `textboxes` and 25 `checkboxes` in a `winform` and I want to be able to type in these `textboxes` and check `checkboxes` and have the corresponding records returned when the statement is executed. At this point whenever I have a select statement with no `checkboxes` referenced in the where clause I can search by any `textbox` and have my records returned normally, however when I add in a search by `checkbox` , no records are returned except ones with  the certain `checkboxes` checked. So if I typed anything in the `textboxes` and didn't check a `checkbox` , I would still get the no record found message.

```
{


        con.Open();
        string str = "select * from engineering where (JobNumber like '%' + @search + '%' AND DateOrdered
        like '%' + @search1 + '%' AND Title like '%' + @search2 + '%' AND PhysicalAddressComplete like 
        '%' + @search3 + '%' AND County like '%' + @search4 + '%' AND Client like '%' + @search5 + '%' 
        AND Contact like '%' + @search6 + '%' AND ContactTitle like '%' + @search7 + '%' AND 
        MailingAddressComplete like '%' + @search8 + '%' AND BusinessPhone like '%' + @search9 + '%' 
        AND CellPhone like '%' + @search10 + '%' AND Email like '%' + @search11 + '%' AND OpenStatus 
        like '%' + @search12 + '%' AND CloseStatus like '%' + @search13 + '%' AND Cabinet 
        like '%' + @search14 + '%' AND Roll like '%' + @search15 + '%' AND Drawer like '%' + @search16 + '%' 
        AND ConstructionDrawings like '%' + @search17 + '%' AND Fee like '%' + @search18 + '%' AND 
        ConstructionCost like '%' + @search19 + '%' AND ProjectDescription like '%' + @search20 + '%' 
        AND DesignBuild like " + DesignBuild + " )";
        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectNumber.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDateOrdered.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectName.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectAddress.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCounty.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClient.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search6", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClientContact.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search7", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtContactTitle.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search8", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBillingAddress.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search9", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBusinessPhone.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search10", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCellPhone.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search11", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search12", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtOpenStatus.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search13", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCloseStatus.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search14", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCabinet.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search15", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtRoll.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search16", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDrawer.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search17", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDrawings.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search18", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFee.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search19", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCost.Text;
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search20", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectDescription.Text;

        try
        {


            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            da.Fill(ss);


            Showdata(pos);
          if (ss.Rows.Count >0)
            {

                this.chkEducational.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Education"] == 1);
                this.chkDesign.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["DesignBuild"] == 1);
                this.chkMedical.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Medical"] == 1);
                this.chkReligious.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Religious"] == 1);
                this.chkMulti.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["MultiFamily"] == 1);
                this.chkStudent.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Student"] == 1);
                this.chkAssisted.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Assisted"] == 1);
                this.chkSingleFamily.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Single"] == 1);
                this.chkBridge.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Bridge"] == 1);
                this.chkIntersection.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Intersection"] == 1);
                this.chkRoadway.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Roadway"] == 1);
                this.chkTransOther.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["TransportationOther"] == 1);
                this.chkRetailSmall.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["SmallRetail"] == 1);
                this.chkRetailLarge.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["LargeRetail"] == 1);
                this.chkParks.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Parks"] == 1);
                this.chkIndustrial.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Industrial"] == 1);
                this.chkUtility.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Utility"] == 1);
                this.chkGCSmall.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["GCSmall"] == 1);
                this.chkGCLarge.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["GCLarge"] == 1);
                this.chkOffice.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Office"] == 1);
                this.chkOther.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Other"] == 1);
                this.chkMunicipal.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Municipal"] == 1);
                this.chkPrivate.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Privates"] == 1);
                this.chkInstitutional.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Institutional"] == 1);
                this.chkMilitary.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Military"] == 1);


            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");

        }


        con.Close();

    }
```

However even still when I do not include the checkbox in the where clause I still get the `"no record found message"` , then once I click out of that message box my results are shown. Any help with either of these two issues would be great.

Comment: Try to display exception message instead of custom message (e.g. `e.Message`). You can get exception details when debugging by setting breakpoint in catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried debugging your code where you are checking `if (ss.Rows.Count >0)`

```
this.chkEducational.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Education"] == 1);
                this.chkDesign.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["DesignBuild"] == 1);
                this.chkMedical.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Medical"] == 1);
                this.chkReligious.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Religious"] == 1);
                this.chkMulti.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["MultiFamily"] == 1);
                this.chkStudent.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Student"] == 1);
                this.chkAssisted.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Assisted"] == 1);
                this.chkSingleFamily.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Single"] == 1);
                this.chkBridge.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Bridge"] == 1);
                this.chkIntersection.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Intersection"] == 1);
                this.chkRoadway.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Roadway"] == 1);
                this.chkTransOther.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["TransportationOther"] == 1);
                this.chkRetailSmall.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["SmallRetail"] == 1);
                this.chkRetailLarge.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["LargeRetail"] == 1);
                this.chkParks.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Parks"] == 1);
                this.chkIndustrial.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Industrial"] == 1);
                this.chkUtility.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Utility"] == 1);
                this.chkGCSmall.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["GCSmall"] == 1);
                this.chkGCLarge.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["GCLarge"] == 1);
                this.chkOffice.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Office"] == 1);
                this.chkOther.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Other"] == 1);
                this.chkMunicipal.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Municipal"] == 1);
                this.chkPrivate.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Privates"] == 1);
                this.chkInstitutional.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Institutional"] == 1);
                this.chkMilitary.Checked = ((int)ss.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()["Military"] == 1);
```

You code is breaking somewhere and that's why it is showing error.

Can you please share screen shot and the data coming in your dataset which is `ss`

Comment: Look at my query, when you see the operand AND, it means that all conditions must be met for a result to be returned. What I did is try using the SQL Manager and run queries using that command stack to see what results I am expecting. If I get no results, the query is too restrictive.

Comment: you have applied the message box in catch that means some exception occurs and it will show message. You need to debug the checkbox section.